# mex function memory leak

Tags: matlab, memory-leaks, mex

I am new to writing MEX-functions and I have a memory problem. The MEXf getaway routine is as follows:

```
void mexFunction (int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs,const mxArray *prhs[]){

double *ecg;                    /*Pointer to double for input data*/
double *outArray;               /*Pointer to double for output data*/
void *dyn;                      /*Pointer to void for the dynamic allocation of memory 
int N=0;
int i=1;
int j=0; 
int k=0;
/*CHECK FOR PROPER NUMBER OF ARGUMENTS*/

if (nrhs != 1 ) mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("EplimitedQRSDetector:NoInput", "This function takes  one input argument: ECG.");
else if(nlhs!=1) mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("EplimitedQRSDetector:NoOutput", "This function requires one output argument.");



/*LOAD INPUT DATA AND ALLOCATE OUTPUT MEMORY*/
ecg=mxGetPr(prhs[0]);                       /*Input data loading*/
N=(int) mxGetM(prhs[0]);                    
plhs[0]=mxCreateDoubleMatrix(0,0,mxREAL); 
dyn = mxCalloc(N,sizeof(double));           /*Dynamic memory allocation*/
outArray=(double*) dyn;                     



/*CALL THE SUBROUTINE*/

for (j=0;j<N;j++){
    outArray[k]=QRSDet(ecg[j], i );         
    if (outArray[k]!=0){ 
        outArray[k]=j-outArray[k];         
        k++;
    }
    i=0;
}


/*FILL THE OUTPUT ARRAY*/

mxSetData(plhs[0], outArray);               
mxSetM(plhs[0], k-1);                       
mxSetN(plhs[0], 1);
mxFree(dyn);
mxFree(outArray);
return;
```

When I call the Mex-function from the matlab command window, i get the error message "maximum variable size allowed by the function is exceeded". Since the function worked well the first few times i used it, I think the problem is that I don't free memory in the right way in my code. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks!

N

Answer (score 2):

The code is now running thanks to the modifications suggested by Navan. In addition to the improper use of mxFree, these 3 lines were causing a segmentation violation:

```
mxSetData(plhs[0], outArray);               
mxSetM(plhs[0], k-1);                       
mxSetN(plhs[0], 1);
```

outArray is pointing to a Nx1 array allocated using mxCalloc, so setting the first dimension of plhs[0] to (k-1)!=N causes the segmentation violation. Once substituted that line with

```
mxSetM(plhs[0], N)
```

the algorithm started to work properly. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you should not call mxFree on the memory you allocated. This needs to go back to MATLAB since that is the output. You are also calling it twice on the same pointer. mxSetData does not copy your data. It sets the pointer.

I think in call to mxSetM you need to pass k instead of k-1 unless you are intentionally ignoring last value.

Comment: Hi, thank you; you are right, i added mxFree quite randomly attempting to fix the problem. In mxSetM I ignore the last value because 'k' is incremented at the end of the computational routine call, so the k-th element of 'OutArray' is actually the one following the last value of interest. The function stops with the same error even after deleting mxFree.

Comment: What is the typical size of input or the value of N?

Comment: It really depends on the application, it can be 10^3 up to 10^6

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with the code. You do need to mxFree existing memory if you are resetting it using mxGetPr. That should be small since it is 0x0.

Comment: Also can you create a local copy first and then create mxArray with correct size and copy data to that instead of setting pointers and using mxCalloc.

Comment: Sorry, I have been busy doing other things, i will implement and test the modifications you suggested as soon as possible. Thank you for helping me.